# Bootstrap 3 Carousel indicators not functioning and no auto-sliding working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I have a testimonial Slider that did slide beautifully a week ago and seems to have stopped working without my changing anything.  The control-indicators are also not functioning.  The carousel is stuck on the first item.

I've checked a million examples and validated the HTML and am going insane.  Note that one carousel is inside another rather static carousel.  When I separate them, the testimonials disappear.  Any help would be appreciated.

Here's the HTML, the CSS is merely formatting and positioning and I have not altered the bootstrap.js

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Wylie For Weight Loss</title>
  <!-- Custom stylesheet -->
  <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Custom stylesheet -->
  <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
  <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">


</head>

<body>

  <!-- ====== Header Section ====== -->
  <header>
    <!-- ====== Menu Section ====== -->
    <div id="main-nav1" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-fixed-carousel nav-bar-scroll" role="navigation">
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-right">
        <ul id="ulnav" class="nav navbar-nav target-changer">
          <li><a href="wylieformedspa.html" style="font-weight:normal; margin-right: 0px; padding-right: 5px;">For MedSpas</a></li>
          <li><a href="wylieforweightloss.html" style="font-weight:normal; margin-left: 5px; padding-left: 5px;"><span style="color: #FFB718;">For WeightLoss Clinics</span></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="images/logo-dark.png" class="img-responsive" id="nav-img"></a>
          <!-- end .navbar-header -->
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-right">
          <ul id="ulnav" class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="ourpos.html">The System</a></li>
            <li><a href="pricing.html">Pricing</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- end .navbar-collapse -->
      </div>
      <!-- end .container -->
    </div>
    <!-- end #main-nav -->

    <!-- ====== End Menu Section ====== -->
  </header>
  <!-- ====== End Header Section ====== -->

  <div id="top">
    <div id="myCarousel">
      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active" style="background: url('images/5.jpg') 50% 0 no-repeat fixed;">
          <div class="center-container">
            <div class="container" style="text-align:center;">
              <div class="slider-content">
                <h2 class="fadeInUp animated delayTwo" style="margin-bottom:0px;">Wylie Business System</h2>
                <p class="fadeInUp animated delayThree">The only business management system your weight loss clinic will need.</p>
                <form class="form-inline" action="weightloss_form-to-email.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input name="name" type="text" id="name" class="sm-form-control required" placeholder="Your name">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input name="email" type="text" id="email" class="required email sm-form-control" placeholder="Your email address">
                  </div>
                  <div style="text-align:center;">
                    <input type="submit" name="Send" value="Get a Demo" class="button button-orange" style="margin:0px; font-weight:bold;">
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- end .top> .container -->

      <div id="testimonialSlider" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" style="margin-top: 0px;">
        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
          <div class="item active">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                <div class="testi-content">
                  <p>I was so happy to come across Will McKinty and Wylie Systems. The POS integrates so well into our clinic and any requested customizations have been implemented with ease. Once we transitioned our existing merchant account to one that
                    directly interfaces with Wylie POS, we were even able to save money on our credit transactions. Wylie always promptly responds to any communications which is also a big plus for me!</p>
                  <div class="testi-meta">
                    JASON SCHNEIDER
                    <span>Weight Loss Couture, St. Louis, Missouri</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                <div class="testi-content">
                  <p>I love how your POS has made our lives at our multiple locations easier to manage. It is user friendly for those that are not as technically inclined (like me). We love that we can do most record keeping and transactions in one place.
                    Prior to using your POS, we had to use many different types of software and applications. Now everything is more streamlined. As easy as it is to use, there are still some instances where I need a bit of advice on how to navigate or
                    improve upon our day to day record keeping, and you have demonstrated exemplary service by always responding to any 'emergencies' I may have in a friendly, quick and efficient manner!</p>
                  <div class="testi-meta">
                    JENNIVINE LEE
                    <span>Lumina Skin, San Francisco, CA</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                <div class="testi-content">
                  <p>We purchased WyliePOS for our weight loss clinic here in Wyoming. The system has been a huge help in the operation of the business. Not only has it dramatically simplified things at the point of sale, the ‘back-end’ functionality has
                    made it easy to track inventories and financials (used to use QuickBooks). Also, ‘Wylie’ has added some very helpful custom features to the system, most notably a patient reporting tool, which tracks patient progress and enables automated
                    reporting to referring physicians.</p>
                  <div class="testi-meta">
                    SCOTT POPP
                    <span>Owner - Popp Chiropractic and Rehabilitation</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                <div class="testi-content">
                  <p>Wylie’s Point of Sale system has been great for our business! They made sure we got up and going as quickly as possible and continue to have stellar after-service support. We also like that on an on-going basis they optimize the product
                    (recently added the ability to manage employee discounting)</p>
                  <div class="testi-meta">
                    TAMARA HAWK MPT
                    <span>Director of Therapies, Cardiac Rehab – Wyoming Medical Center</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                <div class="testi-content">
                  <p>I am glad that I connected with Wylie Systems, I think what I like most is their availability to help solve any concerns immediately– they have never let us down. In addition they have provided a constant stream of improvements to an
                    already great product. The POS is great – it really helps me keep track of and analyse sales without being tied to the office. Going back to the traditional cash register – or even the most modern version – would be a nightmare!</p>
                  <div class="testi-meta">
                    JOHN LESTER
                    <span>Point de Depart, Gatineau, Quebec</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                <div class="testi-content">
                  <p>Wylie Systems Inc. has done several projects for Karrys to help us at the point of sale. The quality of their work and customer support following completion has been excellent.</p>
                  <div class="testi-meta">
                    PETER KERR
                    <span>VP Sales at Karrys Bros. Limited</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                <div class="testi-content">
                  <p>I was so happy to come across Will McKinty and Wylie Systems. The POS integrates so well into our clinic and any requested customizations have been implemented with ease. Once we transitioned our existing merchant account to one that
                    directly interfaces with Wylie POS, we were even able to save money on our credit transactions. Wylie always promptly responds to any communications which is also a big plus for me!</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#testimonialSlider" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#testimonialSlider" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#testimonialSlider" data-slide-to="2"></li>
          <li data-target="#testimonialSlider" data-slide-to="3"></li>
          <li data-target="#testimonialSlider" data-slide-to="4"></li>
          <li data-target="#testimonialSlider" data-slide-to="5"></li>
          <li data-target="#testimonialSlider" data-slide-to="6"></li>
        </ol>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <!-- ====== End Footer ====== -->
  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap 3.2.0 js -->
  <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <!-- jQuery Parallax plugin -->
  <script src="js/jquery.parallax-1.1.3.js"></script>
  <!-- jQuery One Page Nav Plugin -->
  <script src="js/jquery.nav.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.viewportchecker.js"></script>
  <!-- Custom JS -->
  <script src="js/site.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is there any console error log?

Comment: No errors on the console.  I've inherited much of the work and attempting to clean it up.

Comment: Well, that is obvious in hindsight.  I should have tried that first.  I reset the bootstrap.css and bootstrap.js to the online sources (rather than a local copy).  that worked,  Something must have been corrupted in the local source.  my apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myCarousel').carousel({
      interval: 3000
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks @McBern, I had tried that (saw it posted elsewhere).  it looks like my local source for bootstrrap.js and bootstrap.css must have been compromised.  Thanks for the time.

Answer (score 0):

replaced local copies of boostrap.css and bootstrap.js source with:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

and

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Good to know that